# Elliptic Curve Encryption

Tags: elliptic-curves

I know about ECDH when you need 2 pairs of public/private keys.
But I wonder what is a simplest way to encrypt with just single public key?

- Should I select a second random pair of public/private keys for each "boxing"?

or

- I can have a pre-selected publicly known pair of public/"private" keys?

or

- Is there other simpler way to encrypt data with Elliptic Curve encryption?

Comment: I recommend that you consider [ECIES](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.5.1)

Comment: Also dropping in a mention of ElGamal